# How to set Kendo AutoComplete value to " "

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

Using javascript, I have two controls, one dropdownlist and one autocomplete. I am setting a `valueX` based on `dropdownlistA._selectedValue + autocompleteA[0].value`. If there is no value in the autocomplete I want to return " " and not 'undefined' so I can set `valueX` equal to something like "Sam ". I am able to set the dropdownlist value to " ", just not the autocomplete. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

is there a reason you aren't just calling `.value()` on the AutoComplete widget?

```
$("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value()
```

returns the empty string "" if there is no value.

---

Also, don't use `_selectedValue`. It is a loosely followed JavaScript convention that things that start with underscore are "private" and should not be used. There is no guarantee that any properties or functions that start with '_' will still exist in future versions of Kendo.

DropDown has a `.text()` function that you can call to get the text of the selected item.

```
$("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").text()
```

Comment: I'll have to change out the _selectedValue's thanks for heads up. I used the above for the DDL and still breaks expecting a function. Let me add I'm using the autocomplete to fill the void for a textbox from Kendo. I have the datasource set to [] and a placeholder defined. Still not getting past the DDL. The .value helped for the autocomplete.

Comment: how about if the AC control is set to .hide()? Would that cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

After adding the following comments everything worked:

```
var cboSearchString3AC = $("#cboSearchString3AC").kendoAutoComplete({
dataSource: [],
placeholder: "[ Search for... ]"}); //.data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

This was an error on my part.